# Inserting code after each post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, sociable

I am wanting to insert some code after each post in WordPress... I know you can do it after this for example, in single.php

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

However if I do that it puts it in the wrong place.. an example post is here: http://www.hardwareblog.com/348/computer-hardware/top-10-gadget-gift-ideas-to-avoid-this-christmas/  -- if I put it AFTER the code example above it will be placed AFTER the sociable & facebook links..... I want to put it BEFORE those, so it's RIGHT AFTER the post.

I did some checking & testing.. this code here from post-template.php

```
function the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0) {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

It seems the facebook & sociable code is inserted into the output within the apply_filters() function.... though I can't work out where.

Any help on what I am trying to do?

Comment: filters are coded for in either the functions.php theme file or in an addon. To verify this you could try disable relevant plugins and look in that file.

Comment: Well the sociable plugin has it's own files; though not seeing any clues on how to put code above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a filter on the content and the function:

```
    function the_content_replacer($content) 
    {
//global $post, $posts;
       //$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

 $content .= "\n<div style=\"display:none;\">text here</div>"; 

//$content = preg_replace('/="http:\/\/cnn/i', 
// '="http://example.com?http://cnn', $content, -1); 
       return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'the_content_replacer', 1);
```

1. much more examples on this filter on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com ..........
2. You can just copy and paste the piece of content in the file "functions.php" in your theme and it will work.
3. You can also just drop it in the directory wp-content/mu-plugins if your run multisite so it works on all the blogs in your multisite environment.
4. the third parameters determines the importance of when applying the filter, see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/at-what-priority-does-add-filter-overwrite-core-functions

--> it is better to post all WordPress questions in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com !!!

--> if you use e.g.

```
$content .= "\n<div style=\"display:none;\">text here</div>";
```

it will not remove a closing paragraph tag (note the linebreak at the beginning of the string)

Comment: Thanks very much for that - as well as the link to the alternate place to post. I tried the above with the below code..

    function subscription_links($content) {
    
        global $post, $posts;
    
        $content .= '<div style="display:none;">text here</div>';
    
        return $content;
    
    }
    
    add_filter('the_content', 'subscription_links', 1);

It worked fine, however it for some reason stripped the closing </p> tag off the end of the post.

Comment: Hmmmmm not sure why my code I inserted above didn't format correctly. Guess you can't post code in the comments!? Which is a little annoying.

Comment: Ahh ok. But yeah.... I'm trying to put the code outside the paragraph code... thing is whenever I set the third parameter to < 10 it adds it right after the post, but replaces the closing </p> with my code.... if I put the third parameter >= 10 it puts my code AFTER other plugin code & the closing </p> is there like it should be.

Comment: @Brett : if you use 
$content .= "\n<div style=\"display:none;\">text here</div>"; 
instead it will not remove the last paragraph....... (notice the linebreak at the beginning)